# Wrong result when adding two bignums in gass assembler

Tags: assembly, x86-64, twos-complement, bignum

I am adding two big numbers in GAS, I have used the online big number calculator to check the sum first, which is `-396,154,063,093,444,159,558`. I also am using SASM, an asm IDE, and the result from `rcx` is `0x86420a87db9357ba`; from `rdx` is `0xffffffffffffffea`. Combining them results in `0xffffffffffffffea86420a87db9357ba`, which is, in decimal, `340282366920938463067220544338324051898`.
What have I done wrong?
Here is the code:

```
    .section .data
bignum1:
    .octa -198077031546722079779 
bignum2:
    .octa -198077031546722079779
.text
.global main
main:
    movq %rsp, %rbp #for correct debugging
    # write your code here
    movq bignum1, %rax
    movq bignum1 +8, %rbx
    movq bignum2, %rcx
    movq bignum2 + 8, %rdx
    
    addq %rax, %rcx
    adcq %rbx, %rdx    
    
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Comment: You converted unsigned instead of signed.

Comment: Thanks. did not notice that. Do you know any converter for negative hexes?

Comment: Simplest is to subtract 2^128 from the result.

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the math behind this? I do not have a college degree in math.

Comment: In [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the upper half of the unsigned range is repurposed to mean the negative numbers.

Comment: [Here is a little illustration](https://i.imgur.com/fZeuRMi.png)

Comment: Thanks I got it. You calculate the total possible number then minus the result in rdx:rcx. Finally you affix a minus sign and that is it.

Comment: A bit-pattern interpreted as a 2's complement integer has a place-value of -2^{n-1} for the top bit, instead of +2^{n-1} for unsigned, everything else the same.  If you take the unsigned value represented by the bit-pattern, it will be 2x 2^{n-1} = 2^{n} higher than the signed interpretation if that high bit was set, otherwise the same.  So subtracting 2^n from the unsigned "value" gives you the negative value you want.